# HiroMacro - how to setup random times (sleep)

Tags: random, sleep

I'm using this app with [this language](http://prohiro.com/?page_id=399).

In the link above, i'm refering to point 4.2.8 & 4.2.13. I want to merge these 2 bits of code together.

How do I randomise sleep?

For example:

I want to click button 1 and then button 2.
The time between button1 & button2 needs to be randomly chosen from between 1 and 10 seconds.

This is all I could find:

```
rand sleep 1000 10000
```

or

```
Sleep math.random(1000,10000)
```

Would this work?

So far I have

```
:start 
touchdown 0 12 123
touchMove 0 12 123 //this part is clicking Button 1 

var #sleepTime 0
rand #sleepTime 1000 10000
sleep #sleepTime
// The code you provided to randomly wait between 1 and 10 
     seconds 

touchdown 0 12 145
touchMove 0 12 145
//this part is clicking Button 2 
:end
```

Comment: AFAIK HiroMacro doesn't support Lua.

Comment: Ah right, I thought it was Lua. Do you know what language it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write:

```
var #sleepTime 0  
rand #sleepTime 1000 10000  
sleep #sleepTime
```

Using your code, and the examples in the documentation 
(which declares variables before ':start is used)

```
var #sleepTime 0  
:start 
rand #sleepTime 1000 10000  
touchPress 0 100 200
sleep #sleepTime  
touchPress 1 200 200
:end
```

I think you might need to use `touchPress` to simulate a button being pressed.

Comment: Thank you so much Jon. So just to confirm, i need to add this code between the Button1 and Button2 code right?

Comment: i'd have to see your code to tell you that - I couldn't quite understand what you mean by clicking the two buttons but setting a time between them.

Comment: I've added the code below as an answer to my question. Sorry i'm new to the site and not sure how it fully works..

Comment: Thank you so much. I think you are right here. I'm going to test that out now. Thank you ever so much!

Comment: Omg Jon, you absolute legend! It worked!!! Can't wait to add this to my code now. Thanking you ever so much!